# Is logging from multiple celery worker into one file safe?

Tags: python, logging, celery

I run celeryd in prefork mode with cuncurrency > 1 like below:

```
celery worker -c 100 -A x.y.z.tasks -f mylogfile.log --loglevel=INFO -n myworker
```

As Pythons's logging from multiple processes into one file is not safe ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)), does Celery do something about this? Like dispatching logging to main process and open file just once?

What if I redirect all logs to `stderr` (no `-f`) and pipe `stderr` to a file with supervisor?

Comment: Take a gander at [celery/app/log.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/aee706ad5a743e3a51ed40f827bc02e61947902d/celery/app/log.py) and [celery/utils/log.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/d676150e7b45618618d2e5cf2ac4e9bfb108231b/celery/utils/log.py) and see if it use a SocketHandler and separate process for handling the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only master process is handling this log file, so you are safe